# How to know compatible java type for ResultSet column type in runtime?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, type-conversion

Following row  returns concrete RDBMS type. This type depends on RDBMS.

```
resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnTypeName(1)
```

For example in my case it is `VARCHAR`

Is it possible to know in runtime compatible java type ?

In case of when row above returns `VARCHAR` compatible type is `String`.

I want to solve which methods invoke:

```
resultSet.getXXX(...)
```

Comment: You could save it to an `Object` and then parse it to the class you need. You can check the type of the object via `instance of`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the method [`ResultSetMetaData.getColumnClassName(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnClassName-int-):

> Returns the fully-qualified name of the Java class whose instances are manufactured if the method `ResultSet.getObject` is called to retrieve a value from the column. `ResultSet.getObject` may return a subclass of the class returned by this method.

You can also code it out as demonstrated by [the answer of Daniel Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25567915/466862), although then I would opt to use [`ResultSetMetaData.getColumnType(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnType-int-) instead, that way you can switch using the constants of [`java.sql.Types`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html) or (Java 8) [`java.sql.JDBCType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/JDBCType.html).

You can look at Appendix B of the JDBC 4.2 standard to see which SQL types map to which Java types.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

When I did this, I had to implement what was basically a big switch/case statement which obtained the column type name and then executed the relevant resultSet.getXXX() method.

pseudocode:

```
if(type.equals('VARCHAR') {
  String value = resultSet.getString(column)
} else if (type.equals('TIMESTAMP') {
  Date value = resultSet.getDate(column)
} else if (type.equals('INTEGER') {
  Integer value = resultSet.getInteger(column)
} else
  throw new CannotParseTypeFromColumnException("Don't know how to handle type " + type);
}
```

If you do find a better solution, I'd love to know.